# Multiquery PHP PDO - SQL Server 2012 - IIS 8.5

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, query

**Existe algum problema em executar múltiplas queries com o mesmo código PHP PDO?**

Exemplo:

```
<?php

// Retorna $con
include 'conexao.php';

// Suponhamos que dbo.minha_tabela tenha apenas três campos, sendo um deles a chave-primária auto incrementável
$query = "update minha_tabela set coluna = 'valor_da_coluna' where coluna = 'condicao'; ";

$query .= "insert into minha_tabela values('valor_da_coluna', 'valor_da_coluna2'); ";

try{
    $prepare = $con->prepare($query);
    $prepare->execute();

    echo json_encode(array('status' => '200 OK', 'message' => 'query executada com sucesso'));
} catch(\Exception $ex){
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'descrition' => $ex->getMessage(),
            'code' => $ex->getCode()
        )
    );
}
```

Há alguma forma apropriada de se fazer a execução de múltiplas queries com o mesmo comando?

Comment: Um dos problemas é o sql injection (por isso por padrão somente uma consulta é enviada), já imaginou como tratar dois result set ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Eu estou usando [**PDO com *prepared statements***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Eu confundi, quem tem esse comportamento (enviar somente uma consulta `mysqli_query()`, mais de uma `mysqli_multi_query()`) é o MySQLi. Tem uma relacionada no [SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6346674/1342547)

Comment: Isso resolve. Valeu, @rray!!!

Comment: Poder me ajudar aqui//?? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/541703/dados-com-except-n%c3%a3o-funcionam-utilizando-pdo-e-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para não deixar a questão sem resposta.

Não há problemas em executar muitas *queries* com [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php), mas há que se ter cautela, principalmente quando se espera *input* dos usuários.

Uma forma alternativa ao uso de múltiplas *queries* são as [***stored procedures***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx) no banco de dados.

Detalhes:

Para se executar várias queries ao mesmo tempo é preciso que o PHP seja a versão 5.3 ou superior e ***prepared statements*** emulados (usando a flag `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`).

Dessa forma:

```
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES);

try{
    $prepare = $con->prepare($query);
    $prepare->execute();

    echo json_encode(array('status' => '200 OK', 'message' => 'query executada com sucesso'));
} catch(\Exception $ex){
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'descrition' => $ex->getMessage(),
            'code' => $ex->getCode()
        )
    );
}
```